# Taylor remainder of $f(x,y)=\sin x\cdot \cos y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Given $f\colon \mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R,(x,y)\mapsto\sin x\cdot\cos y$ I want to show that there exists $M>0$ such that $$|f(x,y)-T_2(x,y)|\leq M(|x|+|y|)$$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. $T_2$ is the taylor-polynomial of order $2$.

I know I have to consider the remainder of $T_2$. So I calculated all the third partial derivatives:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^3}(x,y)&=-\cos(x)\cos(y)\\
\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial y^3}(x,y)&=\sin(x)\sin(y)\\
\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial y^2\partial x}(x,y)&=\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x\partial y^2}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial y\partial x\partial y}(x,y)=-\cos(x)\cos(y)\\
\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^2\partial y}(x,y)&=\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x\partial y\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial y\partial x^2}(x,y)=\sin(x)\sin(y)
\end{align*}

But now I am really stuck. I looked up the formula for the remainder on wikipedia but I never get the term $|x|+|y|$. So how can you show that $|R_3(x,y)|\leq M(|x|+|y|)$?

Comment: You can't. $f$ is bounded, and $T_2$ is a quadratic polynomial. Hence $\lvert R_3(x,\,y)\rvert$ has quadratic growth, not linear, as such an estimate would imply.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there any chance to get an extimate like above if you change some conditions?

Comment: You get an estimate by $\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert$ if you take the first-order Taylor polynomial. However, Taylor approximations are really only useful near the centre point, the error far away is practically always too large to do anything with the approximation there. _And near the centre point, a quadratic estimate is better than a linear one, cubic yet better_ ... Then you can find an $M > 0$ such that $\lvert R_3(x,y)\rvert < M(\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)^3$, and near $(0,0)$, that gives a much much much better error bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Anyway, the statement in the question is correct, because $T_2(x,y)$ is simply $x$.

Comment: @Landscape Ah, duh. The $\sin x$ factor annihilates the second derivative of $\cos y$ at $(0,0)$. Didn't take that into account.

Comment: @user31035 Since, as Landscape pointed out, $T_2$ actually coincides with the first-order Taylor polynomial, You do have an $M(\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)$ estimate. But to show that, take a lower-order remainder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First compute $T_2(x,y)$ which is given by

> $$ T_2(x,y) = x. $$

Now, we have

$$ \Big| f(x,y)-T_2(x,y)\Big|= \Big| \sin(x)\cos(y)-x\Big|= \Big| \sin(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)+\sin(x)-x\Big|$$

$$ \leq |\sin(x)(\cos(y)-1)|+|\sin(x)|+|x| $$

$$ =|(\cos(y)-1)|+2|x| $$

$$ \leq |y|+2|x|  $$

$$ \leq 2(|x|+|y|). $$

**Note:** The following inequalities

$$ |\sin(x)|\leq |x|,\quad |\cos(y)-1|\leq |y| $$

can be proved using the mean value theorem.